# VBScript: Addition producing a negative number

Tags: html, sql-server, vbscript, asp-classic

I am updating an old VBScript. I was trying to add two variables together in a VBScript function I'm working on, one is a negative while the other is a positive but when the number gets sent back to the SQL table it doesn't calculate correctly. I have code that is similar to this that function correctly when you subtract

EX:-76+4 ends up being -80 instead of -72.

here is code maybe something is wrong with variable.

```
    strSQL = "UPDATE Parts SET On_Hand = '" 
    strSQL = strSQL & (CInt(objRS("On_Hand")) + CInt(Request.Form("QtyIssued"))) & "'"
    strSQL = strSQL & "WHERE Part_ID = '" & Request.Form("PartNum" & x) & "';"
```

Note: I have change Cint from Ccur and still didn't work.

`On_Hand` is also a float in the table.

EDIT: Added full code for clarity

```
  strSQL = "UPDATE Parts SET On_Hand = '" 
  strSQL = strSQL & (CInt(objRS("On_Hand")) + CInt(Request.Form("QtyIssued"))) & "'"
  strSQL = strSQL & "WHERE Part_ID = '" & Request.Form("PartNum" & x) & "';"
  Response.Write strSQL & "<br>"
  objRS.close 
  objRS.Open strSQL, objConn
```

Here is Response Write:

> UPDATE Parts SET On_Hand = '-80'WHERE Part_ID = '15-0219';

Comment: You need to show us what the final string `strSQL` looks like just before you execute it. Then you need to try the same SQL in SSMS.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, `On_hand` *sounds* like it deals with whole numbers, but even if it deals with fractions, why use `float` which is an imprecise data type?

Comment: You need to add the _output_ of `Response.Write strSQL`. We can't see it otherwise. Also you really need to parameterize this code, since you are taking user input and blindly executing it, it is absolutely begging for SQL injection.

Comment: The table was created years ago by someone else I don't understand why On_hand was a float either. It also had a CCur wrap around it too before I tried CInt.

Comment: So your response write shows SQL Server is doing exactly what you tell it to do.

Comment: Well the problem is the that The math is wrong, if it is -76 and you add 4 it should return -72 so maybe something is changing the equation to be minus instead of plus

Comment: Why you passing the `On_hand` in the SQL as a `varchar` you don't need the single quotes around the value being passed in as it should be numeric?

Comment: There's more issues with this code then your approach to the maths. Break the values from `Request.Form` out into variables that way you can sanitise them and make sure the values contain numeric values. That will also make it easy to output the values to debug them on the page. You also need to build a parameterised query using the`ADODB.Command` object.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check your input values coming from the form, as a simple test can debunk your theory that the calculation is wrong.

```vb
<%
Dim sum
Dim x, y

x = -76
y = 4

sum = x + y

Call Response.Write(sum)
Call Response.Write("<br />")

x = "-76"
y = "4"

sum = CInt(x) + CInt(y)

Call Response.Write(sum)
%>
```

Output:

```
-72
-72
```